# What is wrong with this HQL left join query?

Tags: hibernate

Could somebody help me to construct the hibernate query I need?

I have two tables: **Areas** and **AreasLocal**. The first is structured as a tree table to contain the menu of the app, the second acts as an i18n repository for the areas names.

I want to get the **whole areas menu tree as optimized as possible** (eagerly and with the fewer queries as possible) according to the language selected (idLocal attribute).

With the next query I paint the areas tree menu correctly, **except** the localized names, which appear mixed (some areas names in Spanish, others in English, etc.):

```
Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
    "select distinct areas" +
    " from Areas areas" +                       
    " left join fetch areas.children childs " +
    " left join fetch areas.locales locales" +
    " where areas.visible = 1 and areas.parent.idArea = :idArea" +  
    " and areasLocal.id.idLocal = :idLocal " +
    " order by areas.orden ");

query.setParameter("idArea", idArea);
query.setParameter("idLocal", idLocal); 




public class Areas implements Serializable {

    private Integer idArea;
    private Areas parent;
    private Integer idTipoAreas;
    private Boolean visible;
    private Integer orden;
    private Set<Areas> children = new HashSet<Areas>(0);
    private Set<AreasLocal> locales = new HashSet<AreasLocal>(0);

    //setters getters ommited       
}

public class AreasLocal implements Serializable {

    private AreasLocalId id;
    private String name;

    //setters getters ommited       
}



public class AreasLocalId implements Serializable {

    private int idArea;
    private int idLocal;

    //setters getters ommited       

}

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Areas" table="areas">
        <id name="idArea" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID_AREA" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="parent" class="Areas" fetch="select">
            <column name="ID_PARENT"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="idTipoAreas" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ID_TIPO_AREAS" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="visible" type="java.lang.Boolean">
            <column name="ES_VISIBLE" not-null="true" sql-type="bit" />
        </property>
        <property name="orden" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="ORDEN" />
        </property>
        <set name="children" table="areas" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select" order-by="ID_AREA">
            <key>
                <column name="ID_PARENT"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Areas" />
        </set>                
        <set name="locales" table="areas_local" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="ID_AREA"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="AreasLocal" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="AreasLocal" table="areas_local">
        <composite-id name="id" class="AreasLocalId">
            <key-property name="idArea" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="ID_AREA" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="idLocal" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="ID_LOCAL" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have realized that **recursive joins are not admitted in HQL**.

So, you have to do something like this: but also doesn't work as expected, and only the deeper menu which has children is retrieved.

```
Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
    "select distinct areas0" +
    " from Areas areas0" +      

    " left join fetch areas0.children areas1" +
    " left join fetch areas0.locales areas0Locales" +

    " left join fetch areas1.children areas2" +
    " left join fetch areas1.locales areas1Locales" +               

    " left join fetch areas2.children areas3" +
    " left join fetch areas2.locales areas2Locales" +               

    " left join fetch areas3.children areas4" +
    " left join fetch areas3.locales areas3Locales" +               

    //"..." +

    " where areas0.esVisible = 1" +
    " and areas0.parent.idArea = :idArea" +

    " and areas0Locales.id.idLocal = :idLocal " +       
    " and areas1Locales.id.idLocal = :idLocal " +           
    " and areas2Locales.id.idLocal = :idLocal " +           
    " and areas3Locales.id.idLocal = :idLocal " +           

    //"..." +

    " order by areas0.orden ");
```

Any help will be appreciatted